# Open multiple modal reusing same code

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Currently I have written modal code at the end of the same page. I need to open this modal multiple times keeping previously opened modal active. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to create a function? to create a modal? if do you create a function you will be work with this multiple time and manage the context without problem.